# how do i remove an object from a list without bugging the listview in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

Consider the list above. by swiping it to the side I can delete the first element in the row by emitting a deleteEvent.
the object is successfully deleted from the database and a new state "successdeletestate" is emitted by the bloc.

My page listener then has this condition:

```
listener: (BuildContext context, IncomeAndExpenseState state) {
      if (state is SuccessDeleteIncomeAndExpenseState) {
        incomeAndExpensesList.remove(state.incomeExpense);
      }
```

and this happens:
[image]

if I go back and then forth the bug (the positive income showing with the expense value) disappears. Or if I press it I still go to the positive income. it's just the listview that completely bugs out.

tried: building a new list without adding the deleted item
tried: list.removewhere(element => state.element.id == element.id)

they all end up in this mess.

note: the object does extend equatable

Note: these objects have all the same fields EXCEPT a type, which is an enumerator (INCOME,EXEPENSE) that controls the color and the -
that made me think that maybe since the objects are equal but the enum value, the wrong one was being deleted, so i tried with an example like this that ended in the same result:

[image]

[image]

the weird pard is that the left side of the container is properly built, but the right one is built with the stuff from the deleted object. even the colors get mixed.

EDIT:

turns out the data gets mixed up when I send it from the list to the widget you see. and since the left box was rendered outside said widget, it was being built correctly. now I moved it inside and everything bugs, not just the right part. by logic, if I take everything out of that widget file into the list file it should fix it at as well. however, I think that will be terrible

EDIT2 : SOLVED

Answer (score 0):

By making the widget stateless that fixed it.

it does arise some questions for me though. when should i use stateless vs statefull?